# JavaScript code neither working within script tag in HTML code nor in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML code and the javascript part in the  tag is not working. Even if I paste the JavaScript code to external JS file - script.js, it's not working. I tried writing it separately in script.js like this, but that also did not work for me:-

```js
document.getElementById(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";});
document.getElementById(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").style.display="none";});
```

here is the HTML code with JavaScript code written within script tags

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Popup for adding/editing Expertise details</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">Add/Edit</a>
  </div>

  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">

      <div class="register">
        <form method="post" id="register" action="">

          <label> Expertise Area: </label><br>
          <input type="text" name="Fname" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Expertise Area"><br><br>
          <label> Experience: </label><br>
          <label for="quantity">No. of months:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="11">
          <label for="quantity">No. of years:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="50"><br><br>
          <label> Rates </label>
          <label> Remote: </label><br>
          <select id="ph">
            <option>per hour</option>option>
            <option>per topic</option>option>
            <option>per chapter</option>option>
          </select>
          <label for="quantity">Amount in Rs.:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
          <label> Center: </label><br>
          <select id="ph">
            <option>per week</option>option>
            <option>per month</option>option>
          </select>
          <label for="quantity">Amount in Rs.:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
          <label> Learner's Place: </label><br>
          <select id="ph">
            <option>per class</option>option>
            <option>per hour</option>option>
          </select>
          <label for="quantity">Amount in Rs.:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br>
          <label> My Place: </label><br>
          <select id="ph">
            <option>per class</option>option>
            <option>per hour</option>option>
          </select>

          <label for="quantity">Amount in Rs.:</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br><br>
          <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
          <img src="close.png" class="close" alt="Close">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";
    });
    document.getElementById(".close").addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "none";
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a great bug report. Can you please explain what is not happening that you think should?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `getElementById` takes the value of an element's ID attribute. There is no element in your code with an ID of ".button" or "button" for that matter. Note also your option elements are incorrectly closed `</option>option>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.getElementById()` method only gets elements by their `id`-attribute. Therefore use the `document.querySelector()` method for the ".button" and ".close" elements, e.g.:

```js
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";
});
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".popup").style.display="none";
});
```

Comment: Ohh , Thank you so much !

Comment: It worked when i used querySelector instead of getElementByID()

Comment: Perfect +1
You should check if the element is not null before adding an event listener. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have mistaken in writing javascript code.

You are passing a classname `.button` to `getElementById()` method. Replace it with `querySelector()` method. Like this:-

```
document.querySelect(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";});
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.querySelector(".popup").style.display="none";});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a class and not an id You can change your "class" to "id" in your html code and you shouldn't have any problem anymore

Or you can use,

```
getElementsByClassName('.button')[0].addEventListener
```

In your script instead

Any of the two options will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

are you sure the path of the js  file is correct?
Secondly, have you tried to insert a prevent default event to prevent the normal click functionality? Otherwise all the other part of your code could neve been launched

Comment: Please wait until you have enough rep to comment; don't use answers to do so.